# Urban Airship newsstand app

Tags: urbanairship.com, newsstand-kit

I want to implement app for Newsstand using Urban Airship.

But some what confusion in below points:

1) Where I have to upload new content so that, my app can come to know that new content available and user can download it?

2) Should I have to upload content on Urban Airship server?

3) How to download new magazine issue in app?

Is there any proper step by step information for going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what your looking for i do believe: [here](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/29/at-newsstand-and-subscriptions/)